# What are the "Awe-inspiring" weapons statistics?

Tags: dead-island

I have found a hammer called "Awe-inspiring Heavy Hammer" and it has very high force and moderate damage. That's all I noticed ; I'm puzzled, because I have never found this before although I have completed the game 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Dead Island Wiki](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Affixes),  *Awe-inspiring* weapons have high Force and are of *Uncommon* quality.

Comment: Thank u so much, i know that this is a trusty website :-) I'll be sure to share this with my friends if they are stuck

Comment: Welcome on Arqade ! Now, you can mark the question as "answered" (and possibly upvote :D )